# How to call web Services store into list In C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, web-services

I have to bind drop down list using services and for that i am calling services from .cs and using AJAX call i will coll this method and bind drop down list.
But i unable to add this into services. Getting error `Can not implicitly convert 'Seystem.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'Seystem.Collections.Generic.List<MyprojectName.Header.CountryList>`
what i need to do.

```
public Almarai.GiveAway.GetInitiatorList.INITIATORS_LIST GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(string userId, string WorkflowTypeCode) {
            return base.Channel.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userId, WorkflowTypeCode);
        }

[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]

[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0")]
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute(Name="ALM_COUNTRY_M", Namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Almarai.Web.Services.DataEntities")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]

public partial class ALM_COUNTRY_M : object, System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject, 
    System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
    
    [System.NonSerializedAttribute()]
    private System.Runtime.Serialization.ExtensionDataObject extensionDataField;
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private bool COUNTRY_ACTIVEField;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private int COUNTRY_M_IDField;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string CountryCodeField;
    
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.OptionalFieldAttribute()]
    private string CountryNameField;
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string CountryCode {
    get {
        return this.CountryCodeField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CountryCodeField, value) != true)) {
            this.CountryCodeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CountryCode");
        }
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string CountryName {
    get {
        return this.CountryNameField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.CountryNameField, value) != true)) {
            this.CountryNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("CountryName");
        }
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string DivisionCode {
    get {
        return this.DivisionCodeField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DivisionCodeField, value) != true)) {
            this.DivisionCodeField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DivisionCode");
        }
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public int DivisionId {
    get {
        return this.DivisionIdField;
    }
    set {
        if ((this.DivisionIdField.Equals(value) != true)) {
            this.DivisionIdField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DivisionId");
        }
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMemberAttribute()]
public string DivisionName {
    get {
        return this.DivisionNameField;
    }
    set {
        if ((object.ReferenceEquals(this.DivisionNameField, value) != true)) {
            this.DivisionNameField = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged("DivisionName");
        }
    }
}
```

Method:

```
public static List<CountryList> GetCountriesName(string UserID)
{
    GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
    string userid = "approver01";
    string work = "4";
    oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work).ToString();

    List<CountryList> lst = new List<CountryList>();
    lst.Add(oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work));
    return lst;
}
```

Now i have change string to object type but still Error i am getting

```
   public class CountryList
    {
        public INITIATORS_LIST ExtensionData { get; internal set; }
    }
```

I have added Initiator class i am looking these filed to bind with drop down list any one have help me to do same

Please see Screen shots

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221714/discussion-on-question-by-nitish-kumar-patel-how-to-call-web-services-store-into).

Answer (score 2):

After clarifying the return types in your comments:
You are trying to add an object of type `INITIATORS_LIST` to a list of type `CountryList`. To resolve this issue you have to add an object of type `CountryList`:

```
var countryList = new CountryList
{
   ExtensionData = oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work)
};
lst.Add(countryList);
```

instead of:

```
lst.Add(oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work));
```

Depending on your project structure you may need to remove the `internal` modifier on the `set` of your `ExtensionData` property inside your `CountryList` class. If this isn't an option you can add a constructor to the `CountryList` class which takes a `INITIATORS_LIST` as parameter:

```
public class CountryList
{
    public CountryList(INITIATORS_LIST data)
    {
        ExtensionData = data;
    }

    public INITIATORS_LIST ExtensionData { get; internal set; }
}
```

Comment: The only thing missing is the `Name` property, but since OP is unwilling to provide more information hopefully this answer will suffice.

Comment: @John i updated my code as you suggested but still am facing error please help me

Comment: @croxy Please See screen shots i am getting Error

Comment: @croxy I am  not able to Fix this issues Please find my Updated Code

Comment: @NitishKumarPatel Please avoid posting screenshots of errors or code snippets. Always post them as text. This will allow us to copy them quickly. The first error is because you do not return anything adding `return lst;` at the end will fix this. For the second error you need to tell me what the error says.

Comment: @croxy i ma not able to fix this error as your suggested code

Comment: @NitishKumarPatel Your problem is that you are constantly mixing different variable types. Just make sure you assign your defined variables with the right type. Hint: `oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work)` does not return `List<CountryList>` but an object of type `INITIATORS_LIST`. Also make sure the value you return form the method has the same type as the return type defined in the method header. Currently you are mixing `List<string>` and `List<CountryList>`. And once again please **avoid** posting screen shots of your code!

Comment: @croxy I got answerer thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is pretty clear, you can't set a `List<string>` with a `List<CountryList>`.

Either you change function declaration:

```
public static List<string> GetCountriesName(string UserID)
```

Or you change the returned value:

```
return oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work);
```

Assuming you want to return a `List<string>`, you may want to choose which property of `CountryList` will you return and then add it to the list:

```
public static List<CountryList> GetCountriesName(string UserID)
{
    GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient oClient = new GetInitiatorList.MasterDataServiceClient();
    string userid = "approver01";
    string work = "4";

    List<string> lst = new List<string>();
    List<CountryList> countries = oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work);

    foreach (Country c in countries)
    {
        lst.Add(c.Name);
    }

    return lst;
}
```

Comment: You could use `var lst=countries.Select(c=>c.Name).ToList();`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos if it's using LINQ yes, but it doesn't say anything about LINQ either in the question or in the tags..

Comment: yet same error coming

Comment: @AndrésMarotta LINQ is just a namespace, not a data access library. `Enumerable.ToList()` does what this loop does in a single line, without giving wider scope to the list or allowing it to exist in a partially constructed form.

Comment: @NitishKumarPatel you'd never get the same error if you changed the return type. That's the problem in the question's code. It's trying to return the wrong thing. You haven't explained *in the question itself* what the right thing is. A list of names? Or a list of objects?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  return type of oClient.GetInitiatorsListByWorkflow(userid, work); is  ExtensionObject

Comment: @NitishKumarPatel put all that information in the question itself, as text, not images. If you have a compilation error, post the error itself as text, not screenshots of the editor. Screenshots can't be copied, compiled or googled

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavosif you copy my code same error you will get just check once

Comment: @AndrésMarotta Please see my updated code I have modify as you suggested but i am facing error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Please see my Updated code  I have updated my code please check my updated code

Comment: @NitishKumarPatel I don't see any errors, just an unreadable screenshot

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos as per your given code i modify my code but still am fainting error

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos u can see my screen shots